# Homology groups of $(S^2 \times S^2 ) \cup_{S^2} D^3$.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $X$ be $(S^2 \times S^2 )\cup_{S^2} D^3$, where we attach the $3$-disk via the map
>   $$S^2\to S^2 \vee S^2$$
>   which crushes a great circle connecting the north and south poles. Compute the homology groups of $X$.

**My attempt**

I wanted to solve it via Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Let $U$ be a small open neighborhood of $S^2\times S^2$ in $X$, and let $V$ be the interior of the attached $D^3$. Then I thought that $U\cap V$ deformation retracts onto $S^2 \vee S^2$.
And the sequence becomes
$$\to H_k(U\cap V)\to H_k(S^2\times S^2)\to H_k(X)\to H_{k-1}(U\cap V)\to$$

Since $H_k(U\cap V)=0$ unless $k=2$, we get that $H_k(S^2\times S^2)\to H_k(X)$ is an isomorphism for $k=1,3,4$. In the middle of the sequence we have
$$0\to H_2(U\cap V)\to H_2(S^2\times S^2)\to H_2(X)\to 0$$

Then I thought $H_2(X)=(\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z)/\langle (1,1)\rangle\cong \mathbb Z$.

But I was not sure about how to compute $H_2(X)$. Are these right? And could you explain how to compute it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand: you've written the computation of $H_2(X)$ in your answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher Actually I don't understand why I can compute $H_2(X)$ like that and I don't know whether that is right.. I was a little confused about the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, suppose that you have a piece of an exact sequence like this:
$$A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \xrightarrow{h} D \xrightarrow{j} E
$$
and suppose also that you know $A$, $B$, $D$ and $E$, and you know the maps $f$ and $j$.

Then you can immediately deduce that $C$ fits into a "short" exact sequence like this:
$$0 \mapsto \text{coker}(f) \xrightarrow{g_*} C \xrightarrow{h_*} \ker(j) \mapsto 0
$$
where $\text{coker}(f) = B / \text{image}(f)$.

In your setting, you have 
$$H_2(U \cap V) \xrightarrow{f} H_2(S^1 \times S^1) \mapsto H_2(X) \xrightarrow{j} H_{k-1}(U \cap V) \mapsto H_{k-1}(S^1 \times S^1)
$$
and you know that $H_2(X)=0$ and so $\ker(J)=0$, so you get a very short exact sequence
$$0 \mapsto \text{coker}(f) \mapsto H_2(X) \mapsto 0
$$
from which you deduce the isomorphism $\text{coker}(f) \approx H_2(X)$.

So all you have to do now is to verify that $\text{image}(f)$ inside $H_2(S^2 \times S^2) \approx \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ is equal to $\langle (1,1) \rangle$ and you'll be done.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Actually I don't quite know how to compute $H_2(S^2\times S^2)$. I was just told that it can be derived by Künneth theorem. And I don't know why $\text{image}(f)$ inside $H_2(S^2\times S^2) $ is equal to $\langle (1,1)\rangle$. Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course your MV answer would work eventually, but you may use cellular homology as well.

Pick a cellular structure on $X$, say $X^{0}=\mbox{point}$, $X^{1}=X^{0}$, $X^{2}=S^{2}\vee S^{2}$, $X^{3}=X^{2}\cup D^{3}$, $X^{4}=X$. Then $X^{4}/X^{3}=S^{4}$, $X^{3}/X^{2}=S^{3}$, $X^{2}/X^{1}=S^{2}\vee S^{2}$, $X^{1}/X^{0}=\mbox{point}$, and the cellular homology sequence is:

$$H_{4}(S^{4})\rightarrow H_{3}(S^{3})\rightarrow H_{2}(S^{2}\vee S^{2})\rightarrow H_{1}(\mbox{point}),$$

which is

$$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{2}\rightarrow 0,$$

where the first map is zero and second map is $(1,1)$. Hence $H_{4,2,0}=\mathbb{Z}$, zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Lee Mosher's answer and answer what you asked in the comment (I can't leave a comment): You don't need to use the Kunneth theorem to compute $H_2(S^2 \times S^2)$, although you certainly could. Here are two ways:

The first way to see that $H_2(S^2 \times S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is to use cellular homology.

If your first copy of $S^2$ has one 0-cell and one 2-cell $e$, and your second copy of $S^2$ has a single 0-cell and a single 2-cell $e'$, then $S^2 \times S^2$ has cell structure with a single 0-cell, two 2-cells given by $e'$ and $e$, and 1 4-cell $e \times e'$. Then directly from the cellular chain complex you can deduce that $H_2(S^2 \times S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ since all maps in the cellular chain complex will necessarily be zero.

The second way is to consider the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^2 \times S^2, S^2 \vee S^2)$. This gives

$$\cdots \to H_{n+1}(S^2 \times S^2, S^2 \vee S^2) \to H_n(S^2 \vee S^2) \to H_n(S^2 \times S^2) \to H_n(S^2 \times S^2, S^2 \vee S^2) \to \cdots$$

Then excision implies $H_k(S^2 \times S^2, S^2 \vee S^2) \cong \tilde{H}_k((S^2 \times S^2 )/ (S^2 \vee S^2)) \cong \tilde{H}_k(S^2 \wedge S^2) \cong \tilde{H}_k(S^4)$ for all $k$.

This means that when $n=2$ we get that the map $H_n(S^2 \vee S^2) \to H_n(S^2 \times S^2)$ is an isomorphism.

For the image of the map you want, remember that the way the disk gets attached is via the map collapsing a great circle. So $H_2(S^2) \to H_2(S^2 \vee S^2)$ sends $1 \mapsto (1,1)$. But then $H_2(S^2 \vee S^2) \to H_2(S^2 \times S^2)$ preserves $(1,1)$, which is more easily seen using the cellular structure argument above (I'm not quite confident about this explanation about the image, so any confirmation or explanation otherwise would be helpful).